# Adding a new unit to a Dense layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to implement an incremental model, which adds a new unit in the output layer for each new class we add, and freeze all units but the new added one and train until converge, then unfreeze all layers and train the model based on specific loss function.

It seems like there isn't any method in Tensorflow to do that, so I tried to copy the existing weights for the Dense layer before adding the new unit, then create a new Dense layer and try to initialize the new Dense layer after modifying the weights to be in the right shape but I do not know how to let the old weights non-trainable, and the new weights trainable.

The following code describe what I did:

```
    s = tf.keras.Sequential(
      [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=100),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10)
      ]
    )
    s.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE)
    s.fit(x_train, y_train)
    for i in range(len(s.layers)):
        s.layers[i].trainable = False
    # add a new weight for the new task
    w = s.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
    nw = np.zeros((w.shape[0], w.shape[1]+1))
    for i in range(100):
        nw[i] = np.append(w[i], np.array([0.0]))
    b = s.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
    nb = np.zeros((b.shape[0] + 1,))
    nb = np.append(b, [0.0])
    ns = tf.keras.Sequential(s.layers[:-1])
    ns.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=11))
    ns.build((None, 100))
    ns.layers[-1].set_weights([nw, nb])
    ns.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE)
    y_train = np.random.rand(20, 11)
    ns.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

**EDIT**

After the comment from Kaveh, the following idea comes to my mind,
adding a new layer for each class we want to add seems impractical, so given that I will retrain the whole model, can I create a new output layer for the new node, train it while freezing the old layers, then create a new layer with number of units equal to the sum of the two output layers, and intitalize it with the weights of the two ouput layers, thus avoiding the increase in number of layers, so is this a good way?

Comment: I think you can use functional API to resolve this. Define a model that has 2 outputs. Add another output to your model, from the layer before your last layer. Then define a new layer and create new model and add it as your new output.  For old layers to remain intact, in the ``for`` loop just set ``layer.trainable=False`` for ``layers[:-1]`` and let last layer remain trainable.

Comment: @Kaveh Can you please explain that more? also I may repeat the process of adding a new class a lot, so is your method still applicable?

Comment: When you freeze the old model, you should be sure that it extracts the whole features needed to classify the new classes, if not, you have to retrain your whole model.